# How can I check if answer the user typed in is unique in the form submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So, I have a form that has security questions and textfields for the user to type in their answer. I want to prevent the user from typing in the same answer to every security question selected. So I am wondering, if there is a .NET attribute I can use to do validation on client side or server side approach that would prevent duplicate answer submission. Every answer that the user types in has to be unique.

So, How can I check if answer the user typed in is unique in the form submission?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4

Comment: Are you using Webforms by any chance, if not, what are you using?

Comment: It's in the tags. ASP.NET MVC 4

Comment: Sorry, I rarely look at the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably having a custom validation component built for this purpose. It is reusable once implemented and follows the pattern of validators used for MVC4.

[Adding Custom Validator for MVC4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613330/Building-Client-JavaScript-Custom-Validation-in-AS)

To check for the uniqueness:

In C#:

1. Get all the input values in the text boxes into a collection.
2. Check if the length of unique values is the same as length of the collection: `bool cintainsDuplicates = items.Distinct().Count() != items.Length;`

In Javascript in case you choose to build custom validator:

1. Same, get all the values in a collection, probably by class that
   will be assigned to all boxes of that type.
2. Use one of the suggested solutions here to check for duplicates: [Google Search Results](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20make%20sure%20all%20values%20are%20unique%20in%20array)

Comment: Okay but how do I know how to not have duplicate textareas? I'm confused on how to set up that logic?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Why check if the length of the unique values is the same as the length of the collection? I don't want to check for length but actually context?

Comment: That's just the way to determine if there are any non unique values. If you would have a number of colored tennis balls in some basket and select one of each color. If the number of balls in the basket would match the number of balls you have selected, you can conclude they were all unique. If there is more balls in the basket than in your selected set, there were definitely some duplicated.

Answer (score -1):

I think that using Compare will solve your problem. You can try using an equation where you can make sure that the user input is != to the questions that you already have.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more?  How will using Compare solve the problem?